# Three.js: Sprite Material with file texture disappears when changing camera location

Tags: three.js

I am working with Three.js and I encounter strange behavior: when I manipulate the camera location (after user's gestures), this object disappear and come back after additional manipulations. Sometimes they don't exist at first and get shown after relocating the camera.
The camera is defined that way:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 100000);
```

The objects are defined that way:

```
new THREE.TextureLoader().load(imageUrl,
                function(texture){
                    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
                    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
                    var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: true});
                    var marker = new THREE.Sprite(material);
                    scene.add(marker); })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to minimize your view frustum by changing the near and far values. E.g.: set near to `0.1` and far to `10000`. Besides `useScreenCoordinates` is a deprecated parameter of `SpriteMaterial` and has no effect anymore.

Comment: It doesn't fix it, unfortunately.

Comment: Um, can you demonstrate the issue in a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)?